# How can I set dowload folder location to S3 bucket in selenium hub java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, amazon-s3

I am using java in one ec2 machine and selenium hub + node machine in another machine.
So when I download file It should go to s3 bucket, how can I change my firefox options such that download file directly goes to the s3 bucket rather than my client machine download folder

```
firefoxOptions.addPreference("browser.download.dir", folderPath);
```

or something like that because this feature exist in selenoid
https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_uploading_files_to_s3

Comment: I use this for chromoptions but not sure for firefox. Can you try this `put("download.default_directory", downloadpath);`

Comment: I want to directly download to amazon s3 bucket @NandanA, Do you put downloadpath of s3 bucket into the chromeoptions ? does it work ?

Comment: I use current project directory like this `System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\downloads"` so It works for me